# Можно ли на вопрос:

Tags: лексика

Можно ли на вопрос:

```
Вы представляете себе поездку на велосипеде?
```

Ответить так:

```
Это не имеет значения?
```

Answer (score 1):

В целом так ответить можно. Но ответ означает "Не имеет значения, представляю я или нет". Ответ странный, так как обычно человек или представляет себе что-то, или не имеет представления.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно знать контекст этих вопроса и ответа. Без него обе фразы выглядят бессмысленно.

Comment: Контекста нет.